# SpaCy similarity score makes no sense

Tags: spacy

I am trying to figure out if I trust SpaCy's similarity function and I am getting confused.  Here's my toy example:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc1 = nlp(u'Unsalted butter')
doc2 = nlp(u'babi carrot peel babi carrot grim french babi fresh babi roundi fresh exot petit petit peel shred carrot dole shred')

doc1.similarity(doc2)
```

I get the similarity of 0.64.  How can it be this high for two sentences with no overlapping tokens?  Could someone please explain this to me?  Thank you!

Comment: which english model are you using?

Comment: Similarity works using word vectors, not simply tokens. It seems that SpaCy might have found some similarity in that the two sentences talk about some food stuff.

Comment: Have a look at the related discussion on stackexchange cross validated on [how the .similarity() method in SpaCy is computed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304217/how-is-the-similarity-method-in-spacy-computed)

Comment: They both contain foods so they are similar in that respect. Try with "Donald Trump is America's president. Think about that for a moment". Should get a lower score...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `en` model which is most likely linked to `en_core_web_sm`.

The `en_core_web_sm` model doesn't have pretrained glove vectors, so you are using the vectors produced by NER, PoS and DEP tagger to compute similarity.
These vectors encode structural information, e.g. having the same PoS tag or DEP role in the sentence. There is no semantic information encoded in these vectors, so the result you are getting is as expected, weird.

Have also a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49877495/spacy-similarity-function/54484501#54484501).

Comment: Yes, and it is too bad that 'sm' is being used and so the OP is not using word vectors.  However, even with the word vectors, I am finding the values are too high.  I do a pairwise similarity on two collections of documents and nothing is below 0.5.  This is so even if I were to just use all POS-tagged nouns in the documents.